# Why is my 3-prong dryer outlet showing 240V between hot and neutral/ground 'L' prong?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dryer

I'm trying to tell what might be wired wrong with our dryer outlet. Using a Fluke 75 set to AC, I read 238V between the hot leads, 118V from one lead to ground, and 238V between the other lead to ground. Is this a simple breaker box problem or might I have bigger issues? FYI, the house was built in 1977 but I've been told the wiring is copper not aluminum.

I am comfortable doing the fix if I have good debugging tips...

**Corrections now that I'm home:** It's 120v between h1-h2, 120v between h2-neutral, and 240 between h1-neutral. Major user error in data collection but I feel better knowing it's just wired wrong. Please delete or edit at your whim. Also please ding the upvotes because it's a flawed question with bad data.

Comment: Is there a metal water pipe within reach of your meter?  If so, measure between L1 and the pipe (ground), between L2 and the pipe, and neural and the pipe. You should see ~120V L1-pipe, ~120V L2-pipe, and 0V N-pipe.  Is this a 3 or 4 prong receptacle? Is it fed from a subpanel, or the main panel?  What readings do you get back at the breaker?

Comment: Did you check the batteries in your meter?

Comment: Aluminum wiring is actually preferred for high load lines, providing that you increase the guage of the aluminum wire appropriately.  The problem with 1970's aluminum wire is that it maintains the same guage that copper used, which was a big mistake.  The high voltage power lines feeding your house along the power grid are aluminum, it can be safe if the design / installation is not botched.  Anything (including copper) is unsafe it the design or installation is botched.

Comment: @Tester101 There isn't a cold pipe in the room except the fitting for the washer. Have not checked the batteries. It's a borrowed multimeter from work. I will do that. There is only the one breaker box on the back of the house as far as I can tell. There is a double breaker for the dryer there. I have not done anything at the box because I don't think I can identify the connections without a proper diagram. Will look at that tonight.

Comment: This scenario seems impossible to me. The only possible way that the two hots have 240v between them is if they are (properly) connected to the different supply phases. Likewise, the 120v to ground from *one* leg demonstrates that the third prong is *either* neutral or ground (which should both be the same).
It is simply not possible that the other leg meters 240v to ground. The numbers don't add up. Please take the meter reading again, and perhaps post pics of the configuration and reading.

Comment: @B0nk3r You're not taking measurements with the washer plugged in, are you? i.e. you're not pulling the plug partially out, and touching the probes to the blades on the plug?

Comment: I know this is impossible. That's why I asked here. I did fully remove the plug before testing. I did have to wiggle the test leads around a little to make the connection. My supervisor is a EE with 35 years of experience and he thinks it's likely the Fluke holding the last value(a known bug on some of their benchtop meters) and I'm consistently testing the same hot-neutral after testing the two hot leads. I will confirm tonight. Could it be a bad outlet? Anyway, I'll get readings with pictures tonight.

Comment: No need to take anyone's word on the copper vs. aluminum thing. It's pretty obvious if you look at your wiring. Aluminum wires need to be buffed clean and smeared with an anti-oxidation compound before splicing. They also look, well, like aluminum (gray and shiny) rather than like copper (coppery and shiny) when you buff the exposed wire.

Comment: What made you decide to test the voltage in the first place? Did the dryer stop working, or has it never worked?

Comment: @BMitch My wife complained about getting shocked(buzzed in her arm) when she was putting wet towels inside. I checked the ground strap and all three cord terminals and they were affixed correctly. I borrowed the multimeter to check the outlet ground when this Hot-Neutral 240v silliness started. Ultimately, I'm just trying to keep her around as long as possible. FYI, the dryer seems to be working properly otherwise and has dried at least 5-10 loads since we moved in.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I had a house built in 1974 with aluminium wiring, but the gauge was fine - the branch circuits were all 12AWG where normally they'd be 14. That is a concern for sure, but the problems I am aware of are more like: poor connections combined with thermal expansion causing arcing (also happens with fuse boxes); worn out switches/plugs (not specific to AL but still a problem with old wiring); no anti-oxidizer used; people improperly retrofitting in non-CO/ALR fixtures; and not enough circuits leading to blown fuses leading to putting in fuses rated too high and overloading the wire.

Comment: @B0nk3r if your wife was getting shocked when using the machine, I would replace the machine immediately.

Comment: As soon as I can confirm it's the machine and not the house wiring, I will.

Comment: I really appreciate all the feedback! I really don't know which answer to check because my question was flawed.

Comment: @B0nk3r I think you should select BMitch's updated and correct answer.

Comment: @MatthewPK done and lesson learned about composing questions the day after...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your updated readings (120v between h1-h2, 120v between h2-neutral, and 240 between h1-neutral), it looks like Hot2 and Neutral have been reversed. Shutoff the breaker, verify there's no voltage, open the outlet, and correct the wiring so you can dry clothes without getting zapped. In the end, you should have this:

[image: Proper voltage measurement diagram]

Comment: +1 based on the new readings, this answer is correct. I am quite surprised that this mis-wiring didn't have significant consequences.. and that the machine still worked! @BMitch, I would indicate in the answer what the readings are that you're referencing... this question is a bit hard to follow with the revisions.

Comment: Where does the earth pin connect to in that socket?

Comment: On that specific socket, it doesn't appear to have a ground. There are different styles of 240v outlets for different amp levels, and like 2 vs 3 prong 120v receptacles, not all of them have a ground. Some 240v have a ground in place of a neutral, and others have 4 prongs for 2 hots, a ground, and a neutral. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/26964/2196.

Answer (score 7):

***This answer was based on a prior version of the question***

The picture that Jeremy posted in his answer you is perfect. I do however disagree with the idea that there may be a short between ground and neutral. Ground and neutral should be at the same potential and intentionally connected/ bonded in the breaker box.

As far as the readings you are getting L1 to Ground/neutral = 120vac and L2 to ground/neutral = 240vac, this leads me to believe there may be an interconnection of the two power leads. It would seem to me however, if they were somehow interconnected, you would see 240vac on either leg to ground.

I would suggest taking the cover off the plug and testing the hot leads to the neural lug and case ground again. Obviously be careful and skilled with working with open wiring! The next step would be to take the same measurements at the breaker. It should be a double pole 30 amp breaker. Look for any double taps off one leg of the breaker. The readings should be 120 to ground/neutral from each side of the breaker and 240 across the hot lugs of the breakers.  If the same error exists, you may need to turn off the breaker, remove it and disconnect the wires and ohm out the individual paths looking for any shorts in the cable itself. This must be done with the wires disconnected from all power sources. Be sure to check for any voltage, even with wires off the breaker, before proceeding, just in case there is some other interconnection to a hot line.

This trouble shooting is dangerous and should only be attempted by someone qualified. If you are not sure of your abilities, call a pro.

I gotta think about this one a bit more. This situation and readings sound strange and improbable. Maybe one of my electrical guru buds on here can lend some better ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It is a double pole 30 amp breaker at the main box. This is a strange problem and it's starting to look like it might be out of my skillset to deal with. I'm not totally deterred yet though.

Comment: IF there were a short between the two hot leads, his breaker would trip or house would burn down.

Comment: @ matthew:  Sorry you are wrong.  Breakers are current activated, not voltage tripped.  Connecting the two legs will not trip the breaker. They are connected in every intentional 240vac appliance. Example; both legs used to power a 240volt heating element.

Comment: @shirlockhomes It *should* trip if you get a dead short between the legs.  Consider [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law), I=E/R. In a dead short, resistance will be 0 (or close enough anyway) I=240V/0. The circuit will draw an infinite current (or some crap like that), and the breaker will trip (or start the wires on fire). A 240V heating element adds resistance to the circuit, and so prevents an infinite current draw.

Comment: Here's some math. #8 copper has 0.6401 Ohms/1000', so... I=240V/0.6401 Ohms = 374.941 A. I'd say that's enough to trip a breaker. That's like a 500' long ~90,000W (300,000 BTU/hr) heating element, running though your walls.

Comment: You cannot draw current from separate 120vac transformer supplied voltage sources without a path to ground. i may be absolutely wrong here, but have seen black and red on 240vac circuits touch without incident.  Reason a double pole breaker is mechanically tied together is each leg is drawing current to ground, often at different rates. The current loop is not between the legs, but legs to ground.

Comment: @shirlockhomes If the load is perfectly balanced, then there will be no current on the neutral/ground.

Comment: @shirlockhomes the fact that a potential exists across them means, by definition, current will flow. LT2

Comment: @shirlockhomes It's not separate 120V transformers, it's a 240V transformer with a center tap [See](http://www.beananimal.com/media/3180/split%20phase%20small.gif). If the black and red touch, you've completed the circuit.

Comment: OK guys, I'm convinced and stand corrected. Good diagram Tester

Comment: @shirlockhomes, If they were on the same phase the voltage drawn will be 0, but as they are on different phases, at the point that 1 lead is at +110v, then other will be close to -110v.

Answer (score 6):

***This answer was based on a prior version of the question***

I'm going to convert my comment to an answer and elaborate a bit on a comment left by @Tester101.

What you're describing here is not possible with residential electrical, unless you are testing with the washer plugged in (in which case all bets are off).

A 240V reading across your hot leads demonstrates that they are properly connected to the opposite phases of your supply. There is no other way reasonable way you could get such a reading.

The fact that one hot lead to neutral reads 120V likewise indicates it is correct. The voltage of a single supply phase to the neutral is 120V.

The wildcard (and user error, in my opinion) is that you claim the other hot lead reads 240V to neutral. The supply cannot be wired this way, and no erroneous circuity I can think of would result in such a reading.

For simplicity, you expect one hot leg to be -120V and the other to be +120V. Then, with neutral of zero you get 240V between the hot legs and 120V between each and the neutral.

Potential is usually considered from the RMS of the AC power wave. And this reading is compared additively.

The only answer applicable here is that your multi-meter is malfunctioning or you are using it improperly.

Here is the relevant math for why your description cannot be accurate (I did it on paper, easier than using the SE math writer, imho)
Section at the top-left are your readings.

[image: voltage math]

Jackie Chan was probably the more appropriate drawing, but I don't have those skills....

Comment: Hopefully it's the meter. I will confirm tonight and get pictures.

Comment: I agree, the readings he is getting are not really possible.

Answer (score 2):

***This answer was based on a prior version of the question***

The readings don't make sense to me either. You might want to borrow another meter to verify it. What led to this investigation in the first place? Did the dryer not run? If you haven't plugged it in, its best to resolve this issue first before trying it. I would check voltages in the breaker box like Shirlock suggest. Make sure somebody hasn't tied onto the circuit somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

There does not seem to be a problem in this case. your breaker box does not regulate any voltage supply, (only cuts the supply in the case of a short)

Your power grid is supplied at a higher voltage (around 3300v), to your home, at the end of the utilities power grid will be an LV transformer which will transform your supply to the desired voltage. Due to the distances between the transformer and your home, the supply is slightly higher than the norm to allow for some loss within the span of cable.

This supply voltage is near to the 120v range, and it is normal to get these voltage levels. 
from Wikipedia:

> national standards specify that the nominal voltage at the source should be 120 V and allow a range of 114 to 126 V ( RMS) (−5% to +5%). Historically 110, 115 and 117 volts have been used at different times and places in North America. Main power is sometimes spoken of as 110; however, 120 is the nominal voltage.

Comment: The voltages are within tolerances, however, in the US it is not normal to measure 240V from L1 to ground/neutral.  You should measure 240V from L1-L2, 120V from L1-ground, and 120V from L2-ground.